# Play framework forms repeated values - dynamically add controls for new values

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, twirl

I'd like to create a Play form that allows users to enter multiple values for a list in my model. Initially the form should show a single text box, but clicking a "+" button should create a new text box to allow them to enter another value.

The closest I've found is the Play framework documentation on repeated values: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaFormHelpers but this only works for forms pre-populated with multiple email addresses (code below for completeness). How could I add a button to dynamically create a text box to allow the user to add a new email?

```
@inputText(myForm("name"))
@repeat(myForm("emails"), min = 1) { emailField =>
    @inputText(emailField)
}
```

In my actual model, the list values are actually objects with multiple fields, but I assume if I can add an email field, I'll be able to construct what I need.

Many thanks,
Jim

Comment: Play won't help you in dynamic client side form generation. You need some JavaScript for it.